# Error compiling iptables using cygwin on android

Tags: android, c++, linux, gcc, android-ndk

I am using my iptables source from https://code.google.com/p/iptables4n1/ because source from netfilter.org has issues compiling using cygwin.

When I run the `ndk-build` from my cmd(Am using windows) the build process runs smoothly until it throws an error. Below is the cmd output of the error.

```
C:/Users/Chike/Desktop/DevSec/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4
```

.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../
arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/iptables/iptables-sta
ndalone.o: in function main:jni/iptables-standalone.c:62: error: undefined refer
ence to 'init_extensions'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/iptables] Error 1

Anyone with solution?

Comment: Using cygwin? You need to be using the NDK's toolchain.

Comment: Please can you be  more specific to your answer? I used cmd since ndk-r5+ is now less dependent to build again but still encountered the same issue.

Comment: If you're running under cygwin, you could be linking using cygwin's ld instead of the NDK toolchain's.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but am not using "cygwin" anymore since I read recently that ndk-r5+ works fine without cygwin. Can you give pratical example of linking the NDK toolchain's Id.

Comment: You don't have to do anything, the compiler does it for you. Anyway, your problem is actually just that you're missing a reference to `init_extensions`. You'll need to provide a more complete example of what you're doing before anyone can give any real help, but you're probably just missing a `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libwhatevertheiptableslibis`.